# Group by 5 minute interval cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

```
SELECT
    timestamp, 
    name,
    count(b.name)
FROM time a, id 
WHERE …
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300, name
```

[image]

I have above table
and want to count `created_at` column
 group by 5 minutes interval of  `created_at` ,
 like  count `create_at`  column
 from `2016-09-01 16:21:29` to `2016-09-01 16:26:29`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use FLOOR() function also for get unique integer for every five minute

```
SELECT timestamp, name, count(b.name) FROM time a, id WHERE … GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)
```